# add similar rows of a datatable in c#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a datatable in which multiple data is populated. Need to check a column which contains same values in different rows and add up all the similar rows into one in the same datatable.

for example
id  pid pname   pAmountex vat   vat
1   4   t1  123 2
2   3   t2  45  3
3   4   t3  56  7
4   3   t4  23  8

in the above table,pid column has similar values 4& 3 .i need to sum up the pamountex,vat column of 1st and 3 rd rows for pid 4 and sum up 2 and 3 rows for pid 3.

Comment: Do you need to keep source rows in the table after adding rows that keep sum? What values are required in id and pname columns for rows that keep sum?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with LINQ:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id");
    dt.Columns.Add("pid");
    dt.Columns.Add("pname");
    dt.Columns.Add("pamountex",typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("vat",typeof(int));

    dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 1, 4, "t1", 123, 2 } );
    dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 2, 3, "t2", 45, 3 } );
    dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 3, 4, "t3", 56, 7 } );
    dt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 4, 3, "t4", 23, 8 } );

    dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("pid") )
        .Where (r => r.Count() > 1)
        .Select (gr => 
            new { id = 0, 
                  pid = gr.Key, 
                  pname = "???", 
                  pamountex = gr.Sum (g => g.Field<int>("pamountex")), 
                  vat = gr.Sum (g => g.Field<int>("vat"))
                })
        .ToList()
        .ForEach( r => dt.Rows.Add( 
                 new object[] { 
                         r.id, 
                         r.pid, 
                         r.pname, 
                         r.pamountex, 
                         r.vat } ));
```

You did not specify what values are required in id and pname columns for rows that keep sum so I added some defaults(id = 0 and pname = "???") - change it according to your needs.
I assumed that rows with source data should stay in the table.